# Yocto Initramfs Transaction Error adding cryptsetup package

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, initramfs

I am using Yocto Warrior on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the meta-tegra layer ( https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra ) to build a root file system for my NVIDIA Jetson Nano.

I want to encrypt a certain partition on my SD Card and so I need the cryptsetup package which is available in openembedded layer. I have already added it to my image and the resulting root file system has it installed.

The problem is that I need to add it to my initramfs in order to decrypt my encrypted volume automatically on boot.

The error I get is shown as:

```
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  50 Packages

Total size: 13 M
Installed size: 52 M
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /proc conflicts between attempted installs of tegra-minimal-init-1.0-r0.aarch64 and base-files-3.0.14-r89.jetson_nano
  file /sys conflicts between attempted installs of tegra-minimal-init-1.0-r0.aarch64 and base-files-3.0.14-r89.jetson_nano

Error Summary
-------------
```

I add the cryptsetup to my bbappend file for the initramfs recipe like this ( shown is the entire bbappend file ):

```
PACKAGE_INSTALL_append = " e2fsprogs-e2fsck e2fsprogs-mke2fs e2fsprogs-tune2fs e2fsprogs-badblocks"
PACKAGE_INSTALL_append = " i2c-tools"
PACKAGE_INSTALL_append = " openssl"
PACKAGE_INSTALL_append = " cryptsetup"
```

If I comment out the cryptsetup line, the initramfs task completes just fine.

Here is the non-appended, original recipe file for the initramfs from meta-tegra:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Minimal initramfs image for Tegra platforms"
LICENSE = "MIT"

TEGRA_INITRD_INSTALL ??= ""
INITRD_FSTYPES ??= "${INITRAMFS_FSTYPES}"

PACKAGE_INSTALL = "\
    tegra-firmware-xusb \
    tegra-minimal-init \
    ${TEGRA_INITRD_INSTALL} \
"

IMAGE_FEATURES = ""
IMAGE_LINGUAS = ""

COPY_LIC_MANIFEST = "0"
COPY_LIC_DIRS = "0"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "(tegra)"

KERNELDEPMODDEPEND = ""

IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE = "8192"
#IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE = "16384"

inherit core-image

IMAGE_FSTYPES = "${INITRD_FSTYPES}"
```

How can I add cryptsetup to the initramfs recipe successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same exact error message, except it was triggered by a different recipe (not cryptsetup, but some custom recipe).

The problem is that both recipes ([tegra-minimal-init_1.0.bb](https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra/blob/warrior-l4t-r32.2/recipes-core/initrdscripts/tegra-minimal-init_1.0.bb#L15)) and [base-files_3.0.14.bb](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3.0.14.bb?h=warrior#n35) try to create the '/sys and '/proc' dirs, but with different permissions (one with 0755, the other with 0555).

What solved it was simply removing the dir creation in tegra-minimal-init_1.0.bb:

```
[eliranl@somehost]$ git diff
diff --git a/meta-tegra/recipes-core/initrdscripts/tegra-minimal-init_1.0.bb b/meta-tegra/recipes-core/initrdscripts/tegra-minimal-init_1.0.bb
index ac16ff1..e7021bb 100644
--- a/meta-tegra/recipes-core/initrdscripts/tegra-minimal-init_1.0.bb
+++ b/meta-tegra/recipes-core/initrdscripts/tegra-minimal-init_1.0.bb
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@ S = "${WORKDIR}"
 
 do_install() {
     install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/init-boot.sh ${D}/init
-    install -d ${D}/proc ${D}/sys ${D}/dev ${D}/tmp ${D}/mnt ${D}/run ${D}/usr
+    install -d ${D}/dev ${D}/tmp ${D}/mnt ${D}/run ${D}/usr
     mknod -m 622 ${D}/dev/console c 5 1
     install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
     if [ -e ${WORKDIR}/platform-preboot-cboot.sh ]; then
```

Alternatively, you can upgrade to 'dunfell', as it was fixed there by changing tegra-minimal-init_1.0.bb to create '/proc' and '/sys' with same permissions as in base-files, or just backport this part from [the specific commit](https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra/commit/16bbb3fc75ad6aff37ce4d4cc681f59be025548f):

```
-    install -d ${D}/proc ${D}/sys ${D}/dev ${D}/tmp ${D}/mnt ${D}/run ${D}/usr
+    install -m 0555 -d ${D}/proc ${D}/sys
+    install -m 0755 -d ${D}/dev ${D}/mnt ${D}/run ${D}/usr
+    install -m 1777 -d ${D}/tmp
```